# How do I get out of the Golden Claw room?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim I wasn't actually looking for the golden claw but ended up in the room with the pillars and got stuck behind one of the pillars.  How do I get back out?

Comment: This is pretty vague.  If you're on PC can you post a screenshot?

Comment: Its on xbox, I thought the pillars led to a secret room and now am stuck behind the pillars.  I got in, just can't figure how to get out

Comment: Load an autosave, if there are any on the xbox...

Comment: Your best bet is probably to load a previous save.

Answer (score 9):

I already got stuck in several places around skyrim.
You can either try :

- Whirlwind Sprint Shout, this can maybe unstuck you,
- Load a previously saved game (or autosaved, or quicksaved).

Good Luck

Comment: Presumable he hasn't yet received the whirlwind sprint as he's doing Bleak Falls Barrow :)

Comment: I ended up just loading a previous save, thanks all.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try going into third person view.  This has allowed me to get out of some stuck situations where I could not while in first person view.

Answer (score -1):

A way I do it is try to move backwards and start jumping backwards or go to the last save which respawns you at a door or start!